# Scrape external web page and get all outbound links

Tags: php, curl, hyperlink, outbound

What I want is simple
Get webpage HTML and scrape all outbound links

what I have so far is

```
  <?php
    function get_content($URL){
          $ch = curl_init();
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
          $data = curl_exec($ch);
          curl_close($ch);
          return $data;
      }


 $html = get_content('http://example.com');
    ?>
```

Comment: Cool. Is there a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Make use of [**`DOMDocument`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html); // <----------- Pass the HTML content you retrieved from get_content()
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $tag) {
         echo $tag->getAttribute('href');
}
```

Comment: I get this error Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Empty string supplied as input in /web/com/138950087830688/main.php on line 14

Comment: That's not problem with this code.. Your cURL is not sending you the HTML response. May i know the website name ?

Comment: You need to add this, `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERIFYPEER, false);` to your existing `cURL`

Comment: like that ?     function get_content($URL){
          $ch = curl_init();
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERIFYPEER, false);
          $data = curl_exec($ch);
          curl_close($ch);
          return $data;
      }

Comment: Warning: curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in /web/com/13895409703065/main.php on line 2 Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Empty string supplied as input in /web/com/13895409703065/main.php on line 7